# Caliburn.Micro best way for use pointer events in GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, caliburn.micro

I have app with xaml code:

```
<GridView
AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True"
CanDragItems="True" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}"
ReorderMode="{Binding IsReorderEnabled}"
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}"
cm:Message.Attach="[Event DragItemsStarting] = [Action DragItemsStarting($source, $eventArgs)]">
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"  HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Left" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Height="100" 
            Width="100"
            cm:Message.Attach="[Event Tapped] = [Action ItemTapped()];
                              [Event Holding] = [Action ItemHolding()];        
                              [Event Drop] = [Action ItemDrop()];    
                              [Event DragOver] = [Action ItemDragOver($source, $eventArgs)]">
            <Grid cm:Message.Attach="[Event PointerReleased] = [Action ItemPointerReleased($source, $eventArgs)];  
                              [Event PointerCaptureLost] = [Action ItemPointerCaptureLost($source, $eventArgs)];  
                              [Event PointerCanceled] = [Action ItemPointerCanceled($source, $eventArgs)];  
                              [Event PointerEntered] = [Action ItemPointerEntered($source, $eventArgs)];    
                              [Event PointerExited] = [Action ItemPointerExited($source, $eventArgs)]">
                                <Image
                                    Source="{Binding ItemImage}" 
                                    MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30"
                                    Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is a more count of events, which I signed with the Caliburn.Micro.
If i use only one or two event, for example:

```
<DataTemplate>
        <Grid Height="100" 
            Width="100"
            cm:Message.Attach="[Event Tapped] = [Action ItemTapped()]">
            <Grid cm:Message.Attach="[Event PointerEntered] = [Action ItemPointerEntered($source, $eventArgs)];    
                              [Event PointerExited] = [Action ItemPointerExited($source, $eventArgs)]">
                                <Image
                                    Source="{Binding ItemImage}" 
                                    MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30"
                                    Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

its working fine! And if I use the full code, sometimes uwp my application crashes:

> The DependencyProperty target is invalid: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid

and random error:

```
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.\r\n  
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.<>c.<.cctor>b__34_7(ActionExecutionContext context)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.<>c.<.cctor>b__34_8(ActionExecutionContext context)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.UpdateContext()\r\n 
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.ElementLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)\r"
```

What's the best way to solve my problem? Best practice for Caliburn.Micro?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with your code. Please provide a minimal reproduce project and reproduce steps.

Comment: sorry, This is a random error! I also can not always repeat it! Right now displays this error.

Comment: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.\r\n  
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.<>c.<.cctor>b__34_7(ActionExecutionContext context)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.<>c.<.cctor>b__34_8(ActionExecutionContext context)\r\n   
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.UpdateContext()\r\n 
at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.ElementLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)\r"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is that I have a very large and complex template in xaml. I do not know how to reduce it.

Comment: in that case, it will be much harder for us to help you although we are glad to help you. We can only give some suggestions which you can try to resolve your issue:1.Using [dump](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugger/2009/12/30/what-is-a-dump-and-how-do-i-create-one/) to catch a crash report.2. Remove event action one by one to find which action lead this error. If conveniently upload your project will be much better.